# How does HDF handle the space freed by deleted datasets without repacking

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables

I am specifically referring to HDF as interfaced with using Pytables/Pandas, but I think this applies to HDF in general.

I know that HDF does not reclaim space once a dataset is deleted, and that you must use h5repack/ptrepack to reclaim that space. My problem with that method is that I've found those tools to be extremely slow, especially for multi-gigabyte (My file is ~20 GB) files. So - it's not practical if you're having to add/delete a derived dataset with some regularity (Say, while debugging the thing that makes that data)

So - my question is what happens to that space where a dataset was deleted if the file is not repacked? Is it just lost until you repack the file? Is it marked as available for storage for the next time you try to write something to the file a-la SQL? In other words - is the freed space at all useful, or do you just need to repack the file every so often?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the code behind PyTables, so can't give an official PyTables development answer. Ask at the PyTables Google Groups site, and Francesc Alted might answer.
In the interim, I wrote a little test to exercise the behavior. The example below has been modified to match my comments on Nov-8. It now creates 3 HDF5 files:

1. In the first one, it creates 5 Tables
2. In the second one, it creates 5 Tables, then deletes them, then creates 5 more tables (with different names)
3. In the third one, 5 Tables are created, and the file closed. The file is reopened, the 5 Tables are deleted, and the file is closed. The file is reopened, 5 more Tables are creates (with different names).

The resulting files are the same size.
My conclusion: PyTables is smart enough to reclaim the allocated (but unused) space when new tables are the same size as the deleted ones. I suspect you might get a different outcome if the new tables are larger.

Simple example below:
Files _1, _2 and _3 are all 114 MB in my tests.

```
import tables as tb
import numpy as np

data1  = np.arange(1000000.)
data2  = 2.0*data1
data3  = 3.0*data1

ds_dt = np.dtype({'names':['data1', 'data2', 'data3'],
                  'formats':[(float), (float), (float)] }) 

rec_arr = np.rec.fromarrays([data1, data2, data3], dtype=ds_dt)

with tb.File('SO_58736920_1.h5','w') as h5f:
        tb1 = h5f.create_table('/','test1',obj=rec_arr)
        tb2 = h5f.create_table('/','test2',obj=rec_arr)
        tb3 = h5f.create_table('/','test3',obj=rec_arr)
        tb4 = h5f.create_table('/','test4',obj=rec_arr)
        tb5 = h5f.create_table('/','test5',obj=rec_arr)

with tb.File('SO_58736920_2.h5','w') as h5f:
        tb1 = h5f.create_table('/','test1',obj=rec_arr)
        tb2 = h5f.create_table('/','test2',obj=rec_arr)
        tb3 = h5f.create_table('/','test3',obj=rec_arr)
        tb4 = h5f.create_table('/','test4',obj=rec_arr)
        tb5 = h5f.create_table('/','test5',obj=rec_arr)
        tb1._f_remove()
        tb2._f_remove()
        tb3._f_remove()
        tb4._f_remove()
        tb5._f_remove()  
        tb11 = h5f.create_table('/','test11',obj=rec_arr)
        tb12 = h5f.create_table('/','test12',obj=rec_arr)
        tb13 = h5f.create_table('/','test13',obj=rec_arr)
        tb14 = h5f.create_table('/','test14',obj=rec_arr)
        tb15 = h5f.create_table('/','test15',obj=rec_arr)

with tb.File('SO_58736920_3.h5','w') as h5f:
        tb1 = h5f.create_table('/','test1',obj=rec_arr)
        tb2 = h5f.create_table('/','test2',obj=rec_arr)
        tb3 = h5f.create_table('/','test3',obj=rec_arr)
        tb4 = h5f.create_table('/','test4',obj=rec_arr)
        tb5 = h5f.create_table('/','test5',obj=rec_arr)

with tb.File('SO_58736920_3.h5','r+') as h5f:
        h5f.root.test1._f_remove()
        h5f.root.test2._f_remove()
        h5f.root.test3._f_remove()
        h5f.root.test4._f_remove()
        h5f.root.test5._f_remove()

with tb.File('SO_58736920_3.h5','r+') as h5f:
        tb11 = h5f.create_table('/','test11',obj=rec_arr)
        tb12 = h5f.create_table('/','test12',obj=rec_arr)
        tb13 = h5f.create_table('/','test13',obj=rec_arr)
        tb14 = h5f.create_table('/','test14',obj=rec_arr)
        tb15 = h5f.create_table('/','test15',obj=rec_arr)
```

Comment: I expanded on your example, doing something similar using Pandas and its HDFStore and to_hdf functions to test what happens when the file is closed and reopened.

Interestingly, at least in Pandas implementation, it seems to be tied to the key. Deleting the data at a key and replacing it seemed to cause the archive to adapt to the new size - but deleting the first key and adding the same data to a different key caused the archive to expand.

Comment: After reading your post, I wondered if my example was too simple? Maybe creating, deleting and (re)creating the tables In one go avoids something in the "real world" (where you would create the tables and close, then reopen and delete some tables and close, then reopen and add more data). So, I modified my example to use 3 `with ... as:` statements to open/close the second HDF5 file 3 times. Turns out I get the same result: The 2 files are the same size. Apparently pandas implements PyTables differently.